# Copy specific columns from one sheet to another using reference of first cell of column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy columns of ws12 sheet in ws22 sheet based on the columns headings in ws22 sheet.

```
Sub secondprogram()

     Dim i As Integer
     Dim j As Integer
     For i = 1 To 3
         MsgBox i
         For j = 1 To 3
                     If Worksheets("ws22").Cells(1, i).Value = Worksheets("ws12").Cells(1, j).Value Then
                    'Worksheets("ws12").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(10000, j)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ws22").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(10000, i))
                     Worksheets("ws22").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(10000, i)).Value = Worksheets("ws12").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(10000, j)).Value
              End If
         Next j
     Next i
End Sub
```

When I am using msgbox, right values are coming. but code is showing error run time error '1004' Application defined or object defined error in the both the lines

```
 Worksheets("ws12").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(10000, j)).Copy _
     Destination:=Worksheets("ws22").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(10000, i))

 Worksheets("ws22").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(10000, i)).Value = _
     Worksheets("ws12").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(10000, j)).Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular module or in ThisWorkBook, every use of `Range()` or `Cells()` which is not qualified with a worksheet will default to the ActiveSheet, so it's good practice to make sure you always qualify them.

So in the line below, even though you qualify `Range()`, the enclosed `Cells()` will each refer to the activesheet.

```
Worksheets("ws22").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(10000, i)).Value = _
     Worksheets("ws12").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(10000, j)).Value
```

To fix the problem you need to be more explicit:

```
Dim ws22 As WorkSheet
Dim ws12 As worksheet

Set ws22 = Worksheets("ws22")
Set ws12 = Worksheets("ws12")

'....

ws22.Range(ws22.Cells(2, i), ws22.Cells(10000, i)).Value = _
     ws12.Range(ws12.Cells(2, j), ws12.Cells(10000, j)).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

With that kind of reference to range object you need to repeat sheet reference. Try with this:

```
 Worksheets("ws12").Range(Worksheets("ws12").Cells(2, j), Worksheets("ws12").Cells(10000, j)).Copy _
     Destination:=Worksheets("ws22").Range(Worksheets("ws22").Cells(2, i), Worksheets("ws22").Cells(10000, i))
```

or a bit shorter:

```
With  Worksheets("ws12")
.Range(.Cells(2, j), .Cells(10000, j)).Copy _
     Destination:=Worksheets("ws22").Range(Worksheets("ws22").Cells(2, i), Worksheets("ws22").Cells(10000, i))
End with
```

Comment: Thank you very much, For understanding purposes, Is there a particular reason for repeating sheet reference ?